# Error getting the contents of a hash

Tags: perl, hash

My perl code looks like this:

```
my $ns = scraper {
    process "table.table tr>td>a", 'files[]' => 'TEXT';     
};
my $mres = $ns->scrape(URI->new($purlToScrape));
if ( ($#{$mres->{files}}) > 0 ) {       
    print Dumper($mres->{files} );
    foreach my $key (keys %{ $mres->{files} }) {
        print @{$mres->{files}}[$key]."\n"; 
    }
}
```

While running:

```
$VAR1 = [
  'Metropolis (1927)',
  'The Adventures of Robin Hood (1938)',
  'King Kong (1933)',
  'The Treasure of the Sierra Madre (1948)',
  'Up (2009)',
  'Lawrence of Arabia (1962)',
];
Not a HASH reference at /root/bash-advanced-scripts/rotten.pl line 28.
```

Line 28 is this:

```
print @{$mres->{files}}[$key]."\n";
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What modules do you use?

Comment: `Dumper` is showing you that `$mres->{files}`is an *array* reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error's coming from the previous line:

```
foreach my $key (keys %{ $mres->{files} })
```

`$mres->{files}` is an array reference, so you can't dereference it as a hash.

Just use

```
for my $file (@{ $mres->{files} }) {
    print $file, "\n";
}
```